# Should vertex labels be unique in a graph?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph-theory, graph-databases

I'm working on a browser-based application that allows users to create graphs, manipulate them and run algorithms on them. Right now a vertex is identified by a unique positive integer, but I want to allow labeled vertices, where the label can be any string. Since the labels are what the user actually sees as the 'name' of the vertex, I'm in a dilemma about whether I should allow duplicate labels and how they should be store. There are a few options in mind:

1. Keep the integer vertex ids and make labels unique as well. This introduces the risk of (programmer) confusion between labels and vertex ids, especially with JS automagically converting numbers to strings.
2. Keep integer vertex ids and allow duplicate labels. More flexible, but more room for user confusion.
3. Eliminate numeric vertex ids altogether, and identify vertices by their (unique) labels. Somehow it doesn't feel right to elevate something that feels like a property to an identifier.
4. *Some other approach?*

I looked at a few graph libraries and each seems to have its own way of handling this. I understand that my question may not have a clear, definitive answer, so opinions and insight are appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: 4) Eliminate vertex ids altogether, and identify vertices by their object identity. This may or may not work depending on what algorithms you want to run and how the user wants to identify (lookup) vertices in their graph.

Comment: "*I want to allow labeled vertices*" - that doesn't sound like you want to *require* labels. If the names are optional anyway, you won't use them in any of your algorithms, and they don't have to be unique. (Of course it may still lead to user confusion if the programmer creates a graph where multiple vertices have the same label, but that's not your responsibility).

Comment: "*the risk of (programmer) confusion between labels and vertex ids, especially with JS automagically converting numbers to strings.*" - since you've tagged your question [[tag:typescript]], that issue should not arise.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, identifying vertices by object identity isn't something I had thought about, but I'll certainly consider it. "doesn't sound like you want to require labels" - the idea was to display the vertex id in place of the label if there's no label set. At the moment that's not feeling like a good design choice.

Comment: @Bergi I am indeed using Typescript, but have been caught unawares by `Object.keys()` returning a `string[]` even when the object's key type is `number`. (My 'adjacency list' is of type `{[from_vertex: number]: {[to_vertex: number]: EdgeData}}`)

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't display vertex ids if the vertex has no label. Rather let the programmer decide what to display - that might be ids by default, but nothing if labels are used and the vertex has none. Do your vertices have (arbitrary) data, does your interface use generics?

Comment: An object's keys are always strings (and symbols), there are no integer keys. The type is right - if you want a number back, you'd need to cast the string. But I'd recommend to use a `Map` instead of an object anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Vertices don't have arbitrary data right now, but might need to in the future. An extra map from vertex identifiers to the arbitrary data might work for that, given I don't identify vertices by their object identity. I'm using generic not in the graph interface but in the definition of the adjacency list type: it is parameterized by `EdgeData`, which can be stuff like weight or edge labels. [Here](https://github.com/nradk/gtpg/blob/master/src/graph_core/graph.ts) is the code if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

> Eliminate numeric vertex ids altogether, and identify vertices by
> their (unique) labels.

No.  In your algorithm implementations you will want to lookup vertices by number - not a string

for more detailed discussion of this: https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/cGraph-Class-Design

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why I will want to lookup vertices by a number (as opposed to a string). Is it because of efficiency concernds due to the way maps/objects are implemented in javascript? Also, contrary to what you said here, the code in the link you provided seems to hide the internal numeric id's and seems to ask users to identify nodes by strings.

Comment: You are correct on both points.  Looking up vertices  using strings would slow down your algorithms so that they would be unusable on graphs of significant size.  However, USERS should identify vertices using the string label.  The application code converts the user label into the internal vertex id.  The users never sees the internal ids.

Answer (score -1):

```
we can maintain a adjecentlist for the graph as node value will have uniqueID generate by  hashvalue of previus node .
Deleting the newnode will be little costly by recalultae the hash.

like  
Take count = 1
class HashValue
{
   getUniqueNodeGenerator();
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
when ever we will create a new node we will caluclate all the previous node created to caluculate the newhash value from existing value
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated by ( 1 and Name of the string )
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 1 and New Node
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 2 and New Node
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 3 and New Node
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 4 and New Node
UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 5 and New Node    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here Lebel 
string getUniqueNode()
{
    calulate uniquenode
}
struct user
{
   string name;
   string UniqueID;
}
class graph
{
    int numvertices;
    list<user> *adjLists;
    bool *visited ;
public:
    graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int src,int dest);
    void DFS(int vertex);
};
```

Comment: This will be basic IDEA to start with.
 When ever we will create a new node we will caluclate all the previous node created to caluculate the newhash value from existing value
    UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated by ( 1 and Name of the string )
    UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 1 and New Node
    UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 2 and New Node
   UniqueID:   Hashvalue should be caluclated Hash Value Of Node 3 and New Node